# Nesting IF statements 2

Tags: google-sheets

This is my basic `IF` statement.  I need to preface this statement so that if the referenced cell is blank it returns a blank field instead of a 0.

```
=IF( (G19) < 9 ,  0 , 100  )
```

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK(g8), “”, g8, IF(g8<9, 0, 100))  Tried this no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula -

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G19),"", IF(G19 < 9 , 0 , 100 ))
```